# How to parameterize a manifold of matrices?

Tags: vector-spaces, manifolds, parametrization

Viewing matrices as manifolds still gives me headaches. Manifolds in the shape of $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ I can handle quite well but $M \subset \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a constraint to deal with In fact I can't depict such higher Manifolds the same way like in normal vector space. For instance what happens to parametrization? Considering a smooth manifolds $M = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \vert \quad x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1\}$ it becomes pretty obvious this is a sphere, parametrized by $\psi(\varphi,\theta) = \left(\begin{array}{c}\cos\varphi\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\varphi)\,\sin(\theta)\\\cos(\theta)\end{array}\right)$ with $\varphi \in[0,2\,\pi]$ and $\theta \in [0,\pi]$.

But how is that transferable to matrices, like the orthogonal group $M = O(n) = \{A \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\vert \quad A^T\,A = \mathbb{1}\}$.

Imagining each matrix as a point, as suggested in a prior post doesn't help a lot. Maybe because it's just a dimension too much?

Comment: Sadly it is a dimension too much. The simplest matrices which are not "vectors" (i.e. not of size $1\times n$ or $n\times 1$) are from $\mathbb R^{2\times 2}$, and even for *that* you need to be able to imagine $4$-dimensional objects - which nobody really can do. Having said that, perhaps $O(2)$ would be easy - it is really $1$-dimensional: all the rotations around the origin, and reflexions across a line through the origin, on a plane. (A rotation is given by an angle of rotation, and a reflexion is given by the angle of the axis, so the lot looks like two disjoint circles!)

Comment: Even when considering surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$, coming up with a parameterization of an implicitly defined submanifold is not  an easy task, generally speaking. Depending on what you're trying to *do* with the parameterization, it is often better to avoid the parameterization problem entirely and do the computations on the ambient space.